# C# Winform Messy/blurry text in Datagrid

Tags: c#, winforms, datagrid

I have one datagrid on my form and it's bound with DataTable
I use this code

```
public void SetDataSource(DataTable dt)
    {            
        dgr.DataSource = null;
        dgr.AutoGenerateColumns = false;            
        dgr.DataSource = dt;                 
    }
```

Everytime I click on header or wants to change combobox the text in cells looks like overriden again and again. Never seen it before, look (this is after the fifth click on header)

[image]

The datagrid is readonly, nothing special is set I tried 
Refresh method
Update method
Update datatable
and many others things but I gave it up ..
Any help will be appreciated

Thank you
Pat

```
 // 
        // dgr
        // 
        this.dgr.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
        this.dgr.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;
        this.dgr.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom) 
        | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left) 
        | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
        this.dgr.AutoSizeColumnsMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
        this.dgr.BackgroundColor = System.Drawing.Color.Lavender;
        dataGridViewCellStyle21.Alignment = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
        dataGridViewCellStyle21.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Control;
        dataGridViewCellStyle21.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        dataGridViewCellStyle21.ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.WindowText;
        dataGridViewCellStyle21.SelectionBackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Highlight;
        dataGridViewCellStyle21.SelectionForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.HighlightText;
        dataGridViewCellStyle21.WrapMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTriState.True;
        this.dgr.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle = dataGridViewCellStyle21;
        this.dgr.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
        this.dgr.Columns.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn[] {
        this.Title,
        this.SKU,
        this.Popularity,
        this.Profitability,
        this.Qty,
        this.Score,
        this.EPT,
        this.QPPF,
        this.Overall,
        this.URL});
        this.dgr.EditMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewEditMode.EditOnEnter;
        this.dgr.Enabled = false;
        this.dgr.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 60);
        this.dgr.MultiSelect = false;
        this.dgr.Name = "dgr";
        this.dgr.RowHeadersWidth = 22;
        dataGridViewCellStyle30.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
        this.dgr.RowsDefaultCellStyle = dataGridViewCellStyle30;
        this.dgr.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1292, 500);
        this.dgr.TabIndex = 4;
        this.dgr.CellDoubleClick += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventHandler(this.dgr_CellDoubleClick);
        this.dgr.CellMouseClick += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellMouseEventHandler(this.dgr_CellMouseClick);
        this.dgr.DataBindingComplete += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventHandler(this.dgr_DataBindingComplete);
        this.dgr.MouseMove += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.dgr_MouseMove);
```

Comment: Is this OwnerDrawn DataGridView or not. Have you played with cell drawing, it looks like PaintBackground of the DataGridView cell is not called at all.

Comment: It's standard grid. I don't use any drawing event. I use these events: EditingControlShowing, DataBindingComplete, DataError, MouseMove

Comment: Could you post some more code, especially when you set up your DataGridView

Comment: can I attach an attachment here?

Comment: I think you can't, but you can edit your question, it will also help others to find the solution for you. Just paste initialization code.

Comment: well it's probably to much code, let me know which part is most important for that question and I will delete the rest. It's messy now

Comment: I can't see why this is happening, is your form responsive? Something is preventing PaintBackground but I can't see what is doing that. Is it something with computer, Windows problem, have you restarted your computer?

Comment: it's happening even on second PC. I'll add the grid from scratch and will see

Comment: Maybe some event keeps executing preventing the control to repaint it's background. Edit your post and delete the code you provided and provide the code that is in designer created method InitialiseComponent. It should be in MainFormQPPF.Designer.cs. Just paste the part where DataGridView is initialized.

Comment: Done, is there anything inappropriate?

Comment: Check the answer, I found the reason for your problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how you managed to set this     `dataGridViewCellStyle30.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;`, but it is making all of your problems, try to change that. It basically doesn't refill your background and new text is drawn over the previous one. Change this to some other color in your dataGridViewCellStyle30.

Comment: Man I owe you a beer. This was exactly the problems (4 days, 4 days it was driving me crazy..) If you ever come to the Czech Republic, let me somehow know, you will drink whole night for free. Big thank you

Comment: Glad I could help. When you try to set this color to transparent for most of other properties, it won't let you, but neither I knew that you can set Transparent color for the style ;-). You can be my quest in Serbia if your path ever gets you here. Btw. I'm planning a trip to Prague next year with my wife so why not, we could toast to WinForms :-D

Comment: well good news for you is I also live in Prague so, see you next year :-)

Comment: You saved my day!!! Just in case, it happens with every color with Alfa channel set to 0.